# angular 6 router active link for 2 different urls

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my site  want to set the active link for different `routes`.

```
  <li routerLinkActive="active"  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
    <a [routerLink]="['/test/']" title="Create">Create</a>
 </li>
```

I want to set the `create` as active menu for the urls `/test`, `/test2` , `/engagement`

Is there any possibility to add the `or condition effect`

Comment: What you ask is unclear : would you like to make a dynamic `routerLink` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like https://github.com/ngrx-utils/ngrx-utils#routerlinkmatch-directive which lets you specify a regex to select links to activate.

Another solution might be nesting those 3 routes into a parent route, and giving the latter the `routerLinkActive` directive, so that all the 3 would become active.